# Laggy touchpad at times in both Ubuntu and Windows. Hardware issue?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, touchpad, lag

I have a XiaoMi Notebook Pro 1st gen and the touchpad is very laggy often, such that the pointer is much slower than my hand. Any software adjustment in control panel doesn't makes little difference. I tried it in Windows 10 as well as in Ubuntu Linux and it has the same problem. 
It is worth mentioning that it only happens sometimes, other times it is very snappy and it does take the settings in control panel in consideration.
Anybody else had this? I'm assuming it's hardware related since it happens on both OS's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after weeks. It seems that the USB-C charger I got off Amazon creates some electrical/magnetical field in the laptop which caused this. I didn't figure it out easily because it doesn't happen right after connecting the charger and it takes a while. 
Using the Apple USB-C charger of my friend didn't cause the issue anymore, so I'll get another charger